# Whistle noise from front wheel/brakes?

Tags: brakes, wheels

I was getting a whistle noise from my wheel and replaced the pads and rotors. Put it back together and same noise. I even took it apart again and regreased everything and lubricated parts that i thought needed it. Still getting a whirling whistle sound when the rotors heat up and I go from a stop to releasing the brake pedal and it'll make the whistle noise. Any pointers on this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year, make, model, and engine of the vehicle in question? Does the noise stop at any time? Or is it constant while driving? Does it change in pitch any with speed?